# Can I vectorize code when data is in a list?

Tags: r, optimization, vectorization

I am in the process of optimizing my code, and I am running into some problems. I know that the greatest speed ups in R come from vectorizing code instead of using loops. However, I have my data in lists, and I am not sure if I can vectorize my code or not. I have tried using the `apply` functions (like `lapply`, `vapply`), but I read that these functions are just for writing cleaner code and are actually using loops under the hood!

Here are my three biggest bottlenecks in my code, though I do not think anything can be done for the first part.

1) Reading data

I work with batches of 1000 matrices of dimensions 277x349. This is the biggest bottleneck in my script, but I alleviated the problem a little bit by using the `doMC` package to take advantage of multiple cores with the `foreach` function. This results in a list containing 1000 277x349 matrices.

For the purposes of the question, say we have a list of 1000 matrices of dimensions 277 x 349

```
# Fake data
l <- list()
for(i in 1:1000) {
  l[[i]] <- matrix(rnorm(277*349), nrow=277, ncol=349)
}
```

2) Bottleneck #1

I need to make comparisons to some reference matrix (of same dimensions). This leads to comparing the 1000 matrices in my list to my reference matrix to get a vector of 1000 distances. If I know that the matrices are of the same dimensions, can I vectorize this step?

Here is some code:

```
# The reference matrix
r <- matrix(rnorm(277*349), nrow=277, ncol=349)
# The number of non NA values in matrix. Do not need to worry about this...
K <- 277*349

# Make a function to calculate distances
distance <- function(xi, xj, K, na.rm=TRUE) {
  sqrt(sum((xi - xj)^2, na.rm=na.rm)/K)
}

# Get a vector containing all the distances
d <- vapply(l, distance, c(0), xj=r, K=K)
```

This step is bearably fast using `vapply`, but it is the third slowest part of the code.

3) Bottleneck #2

I now want to make a weighted average matrix of the J "closest" matrices to my reference matrix. (There is a sorting step, but assume that `d[1] < d[2] < ... < d[1000]` for simplicity). I want to get the weighted average matrix for when J=1,2,...,1000

```
# Get the weighted matrix
weightedMatrix <- function(listOfData, distances, J) {
  # Calculate weights:
  w <- d[1:J]^{-2} / sum(d[1:J]^{-2})

  # Get the weighted average matrix
  # *** I use a loop here ***
  x_bar <- matrix(0, nrow=nrow(listOfData[[1]]), ncol=ncol(listOfData[[1]]))
  for(i in 1:J) {
    x_bar <- x_bar + {listOfData[[i]] * w[i]}
  }

  return(x_bar)
}

# Oh no! Another loop...
res <- list()
for(i in 1:length(l) ) {
  res[[i]] <- weightedMatrix(l, d, J=i)
}
```

I am a little stumped. I do not see an intuitive way to vectorize operations on a list of matrices.

The script that I am writing will be called fairly often, so even a little improvement can add up!

---

**EDIT:**

**RE: 1) Reading data**

I forgot to mention that my data is in a special format, so I have to use a special data reading function to read the data in R. The files are in [netcdf4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetCDF) format, and I am using the `nc_open` function from the package `ncdf4` to access the files, and then I have to use the `ncvar_get` function to read the variable of interest. The nice thing is that the data in the files can be read from disk, and then I can read the data into memory with `ncvar_get` to do operations on them with R.

That being said, although I know the size of my matrices and how many of them I will have, I asked my question with a list of data because the `foreach` function that enables me to do parallel computing outputs the results from the parallel-ized loop in a list. I found that with the `foreach` function, the data reading step was about 3x faster.

I imagine that I can arrange the data as a 3d array afterwards, but maybe the time it takes to allocate the 3d array may take more time than it saves? I will have to try it tomorrow.

---

**EDIT 2:**

Here are some of the timings I took of my script.

Original Script:

```
[1] "Reading data to memory"
user  system elapsed 
176.063  44.070  26.611 

[1] "Calculating Distances"
user  system elapsed 
2.312   0.000   2.308 

[1] "Calculating the best 333 weighted matrices"
user  system elapsed 
63.697  28.495   9.092
```

I made the following improvements thus far: (1) Pre-allocate the list before reading data, (2) Improved the weighted matrix calculations, as per Martin Morgan's suggestion.

```
[1] "Reading data to memory"
user  system elapsed 
192.448  38.578  27.872 

[1] "Calculating Distances"
user  system elapsed 
2.324   0.000   2.326 

[1] "Calculating all 1000 weighted matrices"
user  system elapsed 
1.376   0.000   1.374
```

Some notes:

I use 12 cores in my `foreach` loop to read in the data (`registerDoMC(12)`). The whole script takes approximately 40s / 36s to run before / after the improvements.

The timing for my Bottleneck #2 has improved by quite a bit. Previously, I had been computing only the top third (i.e. 333) of the weighted matrices, but now the script can just calculate all the weighted matrices in a fraction of the original time.

Thanks for the help, I will try tweaking my code later to see if I can change my script to work with 3D arrays instead of lists. I am going to take some time now to verify the calculations just to be sure they work!

Comment: It looks to me like you can easily establish a relation between your weighted matrices. Take advantage of it and it should solve your bottleneck #2.

Comment: Bottleneck #1: since all your matrices have the same size, then you can store them into a 3D array instead of a list of matrices. Then you should be able to fully vectorize that distance operation.

Comment: @flodel Interestingly, once in a 3D array, something along the lines of `sqrt(colMeans((tmp - rr)^2,dims = 2))` doesn't appear much faster than `vapply` at all.

Comment: @flodel Please see my update about storing the data as a 3D array. I think it is faster for me to read in the data into a list using the `foreach` function, but I will try converting it into a 3D array to see if I can speed things up. If what @joran says is correct, I may not need to?

Comment: Check out the `.combine` argument of `foreach`.

Comment: @Roland I just tried to construct a 3D array using the `abind` function from the library `abind`. I made a function, `myAbind <- function(...) abind(..., along=3)`, and added `.combind='myAbind'` as an argument to `foreach`, but it is not 3x slower than just keeping the data in a list!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My 'low hanging fruit' (`scan`; pre-allocate and fill) seem to be not relevant, so...

The operations in the distance calculation sort of look vectorized enough to me. Probably you can squeeze some extra speed out of doing a single distance calculation over all your matrices, but this probably makes the code less understandable.

The weightedMatrix calculation looks like there is room for improvement. Let's calculate

```
w <- d^(-2) / cumsum(d^(-2))
```

For a weighted matrix `m` I think the relationship between successive matrices is just `m' = m * (1 - w[i]) + l[[i]] * w[i]`, so

```
res <- vector("list", length(l))
for (i in seq_along(l))
    if (i == 1L) {
        res[[i]] = l[[i]] * w[[i]]
    } else  {
        res[[i]] = res[[i - 1]] * (1 - w[[i]])  + l[[i]] * w[[i]]
    }
```

This changes the calculation of `res` from quadratic to linear. My thoughts about better than linear performance were just a (probably also misguided) hunch; I haven't pursued that.

Returning to pre-allocate and fill and @flodel's comment, we have

```
f0 <- function(n) {
    ## good: pre-allocate and fill
    l = vector("list", n)
    for (i in seq_along(l))
        l[[i]] = 1
    l
}

f1 <- function(n) {
    ## bad: copy and append
    l = list()
    for (i in seq_len(n))
        l[[i]] = 1
    l
}
```

which produce the same result

```
> identical(f0(100), f1(100))
[1] TRUE
```

but with different performance

```
> sapply(10^(1:5), function(i) system.time(f0(i))[3])
elapsed elapsed elapsed elapsed elapsed 
  0.000   0.000   0.002   0.014   0.134 
> sapply(10^(1:5), function(i) system.time(f1(i))[3])
elapsed elapsed elapsed elapsed elapsed 
  0.000   0.001   0.005   0.253  24.520
```

Even though this does not matter for the scale of the current problem does not matter, it seems like one should adopt the better pre-allocate and fill strategy to avoid having to guess whether it's relevant or not. Better, use the `*apply` or in this case `replicate` family to avoid having to think about it

```
l <- replicate(1000, matrix(rnorm(277*349), nrow=277, ncol=349), simplify=FALSE)
```

Comment: +1. Numerically verified, perfect. Why do you think this can get down to O(log n)?

Comment: You might want to remove that first bit about pre-allocating the list to avoid unnecessary copies, as it is not true for lists.

Comment: Please see my edit regarding the data reading step. On your other notes, I will try pre-allocating the list to see if it helps. I know that pre-allocating vectors is faster, but as @flodel says, it may not be true for lists? I will also get back to you tomorrow about the weightedMatrix calculation! (I didn't bring my work home with me :))

Comment: @flodel probably we mis-communicated about copy and append with lists, so I've clarified that with an explicit example and timings (and for the scale of the problem here it probably does not matter so a red herring).

Comment: @ialm ncdf should generally be 'fast' for data input (and well suited to storing data as an array, so natural to do array-based distance calculations), and the distance calculation for your thousand matrix list is not really slow for the size of data you present (0.7s for me); I wonder what performance you're actually seeing?

Comment: @MartinMorgan The data reading step may be a bit slow because I need to retrieve data from a particular variable stored in 1000 different ncdf files. In addition, the data is stored on a USB external hard drive, which may be a part of the problem. I will update my post with the times from my script soon.

Comment: Putting the data on an SSD might be an option.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra We are working with about 10 TB of data, but analyzing small regions of interest at a time. I think SSDs would cost too much $$$ :)